# In Spain after 1492 what were relations like between converted Jews and converted Muslims?

Tags: jews, spain, inquisition, muslims

Is it possible that there was a closeness between the two communities of new Christians or conversely, did they deliberately avoid each other to dispel any concerns Spain might have had about the converted?

Comment: I do not know if we could talk about "communities", since recent converts were looked down by the "cristianos viejos" (Old Christians, christians that claimed that their ascendants were Christians too) and the constant danger of being accused of being a cryptojew or cryptomuslim by the Inquisition. I would bet most of them would have prefered to avoid being identified as converts, and that would incentivate to avoid the company of other converts (whatever their original religion).

Comment: @SJuan76 not sure about converted Jews, but I'm pretty sure that much of the converted Muslims remained having distinct identity up to their expulsions from Spain. For example, a royal decree banning the Arabic language and "Moorish" dress triggered [an outright rebellion in 1568](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebellion_of_the_Alpujarras_(1568%E2%80%9371)#Causes_of_the_second_rebellion), and the expulsion itself, which happened about a century after the conversion, showed that there were about 300,000 people with identity distinct enough to be picked out for expulsion.